# Как правильно подключать скрипты в Yii2 и где?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Я использую стандартный шаблон Yii2, в ходе разработки возникла необходимость подключить небольшой скрипт на jquery. Но я не понимаю куда его надо цеплять. Подскажите, плиз [image: так выглядит моя структура файлов и папок. Скрипт должен использовать в ContactForm, чтобы работать с chexboxom]

Comment: [yii2 js](https://www.google.com/search?q=yii2+js&oq=yii2+js). Очень много информации на эту тему. Можно через [assets](https://www.google.com/search?q=yii2+asset+js)

Comment: @zakiroof я еще не понимаю, куда именно нужно подключать.....

Comment: Поэтому я вам и хочу помочь с поиском информации(это очень важно). Прочитайте документацию по [ресурсам](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets). Там даже есть отдельная глава по расположению ресурсов. Если после прочтения возникнут вопросы, обращайтесь конкретно по проблеме

Answer (score 1):

В `Yii2` можно подключить `js`-скрипты несколькими способами

1. Прописать подключение `js`-файла в `BundleAsset`. Зарегистрировать данный `asset` внутри `layout` или же `view`

Пример, создаем внутри папки `assets` файл `LoginAsset` (используется на странице авторизации):

```php
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class LoginAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [
        '/css/login.css', //<-- здесь прописываем .css-файлы из папки web/css
        '/css/site.css',
        '/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        ];

    public $js = [ 
        '/js/login.js',//<-- здесь прописываем .js-файлы из папки web/js
        '/js/myfuncs.js',
   ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset', //<-- здесь указываем зависимости без которых не будут работать наши скрипты, например jQuery, обычно данных трех Asset-ов хватает для всего
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];

}
```

В файле шаблоне страницы авторизации (у меня это `views/layouts/logins.php`) регистрируем наш `asset`

```php
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */

use app\assets\LoginAsset; //<-- подключаем наш asset

LoginAsset::register($this); //<-- региструем его
?>
... дале идет html
```

После этого при вызове соответствующего `URL` внутри страницы Вы увидите подключенные `css` и `js`-файлы

2. Подключить `js`-файл `на-лету` т.е непосредственно в `view`

Пример, подключаем сразу на странице авторизации (у меня это `views/login/index.php`)

```php
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model \app\models\forms\LoginForm */
/* @var $url string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use \yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->registerJsFile('login.js');
```

P.S По аналогии с `$this->registerJsFile();` непосредственно в `view` Вы можете `на-лету` создать нужный Вам кусок кода `javascript` используя метод `$this->registerJs('<тут код javascript>');`